# How do I print more than one value per key in Tcl?

Tags: arrays, tcl

```
array set array_in_twos {
    set1 table
    set2 chair
    set1 chair
}

foreach combo [array names array_in_twos] {
    puts "$combo is  $array_in_twos($combo),"
}
```

outputs:

```
set1 is chair,
set2 is chair,
```

It seems the second 'set 1' replaces the first 'set 1'.
how do i print all?

```
set1 is table,
set2 is chair,
set1 is chair,
```

I'm open to other methods if using an array is not the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with arrays *or* dictionaries; both are mappings from keys to values. Instead, you need to use `foreach` with a key-value pair system directly:

```
set pairs {
    set1 table
    set2 chair
    set1 chair
}

foreach {key value} $pairs {
    puts "$key is $value"
}
```

This does actually shorten the code…

Comment: @grege: if the answer was useful to you, you should use the tick mark to accept it, thereby indicating to others that the answer solved your problem.